# how to start tomcat with `script -c` command?

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat

I want to start tomcat with the command:

```
script -c "sh /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/startup.sh"
```

After running the command, the console show the message that tomcat has started successfully.

But `ps -ef | grep tomcat` shows that the tomcat doesn't start.

Then I try to use `script` command without `-c` option:

```
[root@xxx test]#script
Script started, file is typescript01
[root@xxx test]# sh /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/program/java/jdk1.8.0_112
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Then `ps -ef | grep tomcat` shows the tomcat is started.

How can I start tomcat with `script -c`?

Comment: Note your first `ps` doesn't prove tomcat didn't start, only that it didn't _remain_ running, which is different. For the interactive case if you end the `script` subshell (control-D, exit, or logout) does tomcat remain running then? If not it could be dying because of the pty 'hangup', although that should only happen if you or someone changed the config because the default config uses `nohup` to prevent this. Why do you need `script` anyway? normal tomcat shouldn't use the tty. If you just want to log the startup, `path/startup.sh >logfile` should be enough.

Comment: I've tried your test, after cancel the `script`, the tomcat is still running<br/>It is not a particular reason that I use `script -c`command to start tomcat, I just come across this trial and want to figure out the reason why `script -c` can't start a tomcat.<br>thanks,:)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Curiously, I try to add `sleep` to the  command `script -c "/usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/startup.sh && sleep 1m"` as you mentioned,the tomcat can be found in `ps -ef`,so as you said, the tomcat is  actually started,but the pty hangup so the tomcat is shutdown.thanks again.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 And I can also use nohup to start tomcat,`script -c "nohup /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/startup.sh"`,although the `script` command end,but the tomcat can be found in `ps -ef`

Comment: Is the `sh` in that `script -c "sh /usr/program/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.50/bin/startup.sh"`actually required? Ist the  script not set executable?